# Yii2 Use two Models in one GridView

Tags: php, gridview, model, merge, yii2

I have a `GridView` which displays an employee's summary of his/her payslip. Here's a screenshot for more understanding:

[image]

Those highlighted columns come from a different model which is the `User` model while the rest come from the `Payslip` model.

How do I merge 2 models in one `GridView`? Because in `GridView`, it is more likely for you to have a single model to display data. But how about 2 models?

Here's a code in my `Payslip` **model**, note that `getUser()` is generated with `gii` since `user_id` is a foreign key in my `payslip` table:

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['user_id' => 'user_id']);
}

public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->user ? $this->user->fname : 'First Name';
}

public function getLastName()
{
    return $this->user ? $this->user->lname : 'Last Name';
}
```

The `Payslip` **controller**:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new PayslipSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

And then the `Payslip` **view**:

```
<?php   
    echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'payslip_id',
            //'store_id',
            'firstName',
            'lastName',
            'total_earnings',
            'total_deduction',
            'net_pay',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); 
?>
```

BTW, in this example,  I just created payslip #1 manually to give you a demo.

**Additional info:**
The logged in user is a BizAdmin user, and all of BizAdmin's staff users should be displayed in the payslip table (that table above) even if these staff users still don't have any payslip created for them. So by default, that table will be occupied already with staff users under the logged in BizAdmin user, and those staff users who still have no payslips created will be indicated "Create Payslip"

Here's an example in KashFlow:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Update view to:

```
<?php   
    echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'payslip_id',
            //'store_id',
            ['value' => function ($data) {return $data->getFirstName();}, 'label' => 'First Name'],
            ['value' => function ($data) {return $data->getLastName();}, 'label' => 'LastName'],

            'total_earnings',
            'total_deduction',
            'net_pay',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); 
?>
```

And in `$searchModel->search` add you relation, like that:

```
 $query = Payslip::find()->with(['user']);
```

Read for data column - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#data-column